# using __construct to pass values to a new class

Tags: php, class

In my main code file which calls my class I have the following:

```
$api = new voip($_client_id,$_client_secret,$_username,$_password); 
$api->login(); 
$api->getdomaininfo($company);
$api->logout();
```

The class file consists of the following:

```
class voip
{   
    private $_client_id = '';
    private $_client_secret = '';
    private $_username = '';
    private $_password = '';
    protected $_access_token = '';
    protected $_refresh_token = '';
    protected $_api_url = '';
    protected $_endpoint = '';
    protected $_method = '';

    public function __construct($_client_id_passed, $_client_secret_passed, $_username_passed, $_password_passed) {
        $this->_client_id = $_client_id_passed;
        $this->_client_secret = $_client_secret_passed;
        $this->_username = $_username_passed;
        $this->_password = $_password_passed;
    }
```

The end results do not seem to be as desired. So am I properly passing the values into the class file to be utilized correctly? I am not getting an errors so I am just wondering if I am using the __Construct function correctly.

I tried debugging with something simple like this:

```
public function getTok(){
        return $this->_client_id;
}
```

But I am not getting anything back from `echo $api->getTok();`

Comment: The vars you are passing in must have values: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d2d36049f552359f79b363ade6754d661ff90a7c

Comment: The values come from the DB so I will check there. I had tested that before and it worked so not sure why no values are coming in from the DB. Thanks.

Comment: Use `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` and all will be revealed.